# Functional Analysis - Set of Applications is Open and Closed

Tags: functional-analysis, applications, continuity

Let X,Y be two metric spaces, prove the following:

A) The set of bounded discontinuous applications is open in the set of the bounded applications from X to Y.

B)The set of bounded continuous applications is a closed subset of the set of bounded applications from X to Y.

Answer (score 0):

The proof of $(B)$ is a straight generalisation of the [Uniform Limit Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_limit_theorem).

$(A)$ is equivalent to $(B)$.